# UIButtons Animation

Tags: animation, uibutton, core-graphics, layer

I have two UIButtons, the user can select one of them, so when one is selected the other is deselected. I want to animate this change like this :

[image]

I know I need to use Core Graphics, but how can I achieve this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the problem in your question? Are you able to draw those buttons as in those four images above but not animate the movement? Are you able to draw the two states (selected and deselected) but not the half-way selected? Are you not able to draw the buttons in the first place?

Comment: I think I'm able to draw the button on a static state. My problem is 1) I don't know how to change CoreGraphic when the button is selected 2) I don't know how to perform the animation

Answer (score 0):

You want to use linear interpolation on the hover circle graphic.
The way it works is something along these lines:

```
Final Position = [(Destination Position) * Time/TotalTimeForMovement] + [(Origin Position) * (1-Time/TotalTimeForMovement)]
```

Let's say you want to move the white hover graphic from Layer1 to Layer2 in 0.2 seconds when the user shifts his/her mouse from Layer1 to Layer2. In that case, you'd want to update the graphics position every frame, where:

Final Position = [(Layer2 Position) * CurrentTimePassed/0.2] + [(Layer1 Position) * 1-(CurrentTimePassed/0.2)]

So to continue this example: Let's assume that the position of Layer1 is (0, 0) and the position of Layer2 is (10, 0). Then, 0.1 seconds into the movement (assuming that it moves completely in 0.2 seconds), the position of the graphic should be:

```
= (0, 10) * 0.1/0.2 + (0, 0) * 1-(0.1/0.2)
= (0, 10) * 0.5 + (0, 0) * 1-0.5
= (0, 10) * 0.5 + (0, 0) * 0.5
= (0, 5) + (0, 0)
= (0, 5)
```

Which is halway between Layer1 and Layer2. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is on the Core Graphic part, I know how to mask an image with text, but I don't how to animate it

Comment: I hope that you would never write that code yourself. There are two _great_ animation frameworks on iOS at two different levels of abstraction that do this for you.